# Align Instances to Normals - Facing Inwards Instead of Outwards

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am new to geometry nodes and have a question regarding how to properly align the rotation of my object along normals. I watched a few tutorials and see that if I want to align something to face outwards along normals I would use this node set up:
[image]
Now, I am using almost identical set up, the difference being is that I want to distribute hair on a sphere like object with the top part of that object missing, and instead of a curve primitive I have created a "hair" object out of a curve and converted it into mesh. So I am doing exactly the  same thing as above but for some reason the hair are facing inwards and I just can't figure out why this is happening? Can someone please suggest what could be the problem here. Thank you. (I have tried changing "Align To Euler" axis but it doesn't work)
[image]

Comment: look closely . it's not the same! yours is set to x, while the other one is set to z. **HOWEVER** I feel like it's a little overkill to use an 'Align Euler to Vector' node when you **LITERALLY** have a "**Rotation**" output (from the 'distribute points on faces' node). Just use the rotation (output of the 'distribute points on faces ' node) as the rotation (input of the 'instance on points')!!!